# Writing an exporter - learning the API

Tags: python, mesh, export

I'm researching the Blender API while working on a custom
exporter. The features I want to implement are similar to the
[IQM exporter](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/blender-2.74/iqm_export.py). I'm trying to get a better understanding of
some of the API calls used in the IQM exporter.

**1. Calculating Tangents**

IQM calculates the tangents using the code below. Why not use [Mesh.calc_tangents()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=tangents#bpy.types.Mesh.calc_tangents) instead?

```
def calcTangents(self):
    # See "Tangent Space Calculation" at http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html
    for v in self.verts:
        v.tangent = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        v.bitangent = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    for (v0, v1, v2) in self.tris:
        dco1 = v1.coord - v0.coord
        dco2 = v2.coord - v0.coord
        duv1 = v1.uv - v0.uv
        duv2 = v2.uv - v0.uv
        tangent = dco2*duv1.y - dco1*duv2.y
        bitangent = dco2*duv1.x - dco1*duv2.x
        if dco2.cross(dco1).dot(bitangent.cross(tangent)) < 0:
            tangent.negate()
            bitangent.negate()
        v0.tangent += tangent
        v1.tangent += tangent
        v2.tangent += tangent
        v0.bitangent += bitangent
        v1.bitangent += bitangent
        v2.bitangent += bitangent
    for v in self.verts:    
        v.tangent = v.tangent - v.normal*v.tangent.dot(v.normal)
        v.tangent.normalize()
        if v.normal.cross(v.tangent).dot(v.bitangent) < 0:
            v.bitangent = -1.0
        else:
            v.bitangent = 1.0
   # ...
```

**2. Converting the selected object(s) to mesh.**

The `collectMeshes()` function loops over the selected objects
and when the selected object is not a `obj.type == 'MESH'` is
skips the object.  Next it converts the object into a mesh. Why
would you convert an `obj` with the `MESH` type using
[obj.to_mesh()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh)? Isn't an object of type `MESH` already an 
`MESH` ?

```
# ...
def collectMeshes(context, bones, scale, matfun, useskel = True, usecol = False, filetype = 'IQM'):
    vertwarn = []
    objs = context.selected_objects #context.scene.objects
    meshes = []
    for obj in objs:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            data = obj.to_mesh(context.scene, False, 'PREVIEW')
            if not data.polygons:
                continue
# ....
```

**3. calc_split_normals()**

Still in the `collectMeshes()` function, the script calls
[obj.calc_normals_split](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=tangents#bpy.types.Mesh.calc_normals_split). The documentation says *Calculate
split vertex normals, which preserve sharp edges*. The
description is pretty clear, but I'm curious why this function is
used in the first place; could this have a deeper reason? Why not
use the default normals instead? [The call is made here in the
exporter](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/blender-2.74/iqm_export.py#L819).

```
# ...
if not data.polygons:
    continue
data.calc_normals_split()
coordmatrix = obj.matrix_world
normalmatrix = coordmatrix.inverted().transposed()
# ...
```

**4. what's the purpose of this line?**

Continuing in `collectMeshes` I see the `if()` as shown below:

```
# ...
if all([ data.vertices[i].co == data.vertices[face.vertices[0]].co for i in face.vertices[1:] ]):
    continue
# ...
```

What is the purpose of this line. Am I correct to say that it
checks if the vertices of the face are already stored in
`data.vertices`? And if so, it skips this vertex?

**5. Getting the vertices and triangles**

A big chunk of the `collectMeshes()` function deals with
gathering the vertices and indices.  It seems that the IQM
exporter creates a new `Mesh` instance per material; it does this
by creating a key from `obj.name`, `matindex` and a `matfun()`. I'm not
100% of my understanding of the code is correct tbh.

Once it has created a new `Mesh` instance or retrieved an existing one, 
it loops over `face.loop_indices`. The documentation says the following
about a loop: [*reference a single vertex and edge*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh). Therefore iterating
over the `face.loop_indices` and then retrieving the specific loop can be
used to retrieve the different vertex coordinate, uv, normal, etc. 
**Is this a correct understanding of how one would retrieve vertex data?**

The [IQM](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/blender-2.74/iqm_export.py) exporter iterates over `data.polygons` like this:

```
for face in data.polygons:
    if len(face.vertices) < 3:
        continue

    if all([ data.vertices[i].co == data.vertices[face.vertices[0]].co for i in face.vertices[1:] ]):
        print("Already exists", face.vertices[0].co)
        continue

    uvface = uvfaces and uvfaces[face.index]
    material = os.path.basename(uvface.image.filepath) if uvface and uvface.image else ''
    matindex = face.material_index

    try:
        mesh = materials[obj.name, matindex, material] 
    except:
        try:
            matprefix = (data.materials and data.materials[matindex].name) or ''
        except:
            matprefix = ''

        mesh = Mesh(obj.name, matfun(matprefix, material), data.vertices)
        meshes.append(mesh)
        materials[obj.name, matindex, material] = mesh

    verts = mesh.verts
    vertmap = mesh.vertmap
    faceverts = []
    for loopidx in face.loop_indices:
        loop = data.loops[loopidx]
        v = data.vertices[loop.vertex_index]
        vertco = coordmatrix * v.co
```

**6. Storing the triangle indices**

The last thing that `collectMeshes()` does is storing the triangles. The length
of `faceverts` is 4 in most cases. It's looping over the vertices of the current
face, starting at 2 and basically selecting only index 0, 1, 2. Why is index 3
ignored? (it's clear that they change winding order too). See [the specific line of the IQM exporter](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/blender-2.74/iqm_export.py#L936).

```
for i in range(2, len(faceverts)):
    mesh.tris.append((faceverts[0], faceverts[i], faceverts[i-1]))
```

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts.